# How to boot from USB?

Tags: boot, usb, iso

I just installed Ubuntu on my Surface Go 2-tablet using a live bootable USB-stick (flashed with balena-etcher), I want to reinstall and now I struggle to boot from USB. Is there any Ubuntu specific setting or .conf file I need to edit in order to get it working?

Boot from USB is enabled in UEFI, secure boot disabled and USB is set to no.1 boot priority.

Comment: There should be some information in a user manual (a paper copy or a file via the internet) how to boot the computer into a temporary menu. Most computers have a hotkey for that purpose, often F12, F10, F9 or ESC, that you should press or tap repeatedly right after you turn on (or reboot) the computer. Please check which hotkey to use for your Surface Go 2, and try a few times until you are quick enough to make it boot into a temporary menu. Then in that menu, select what looks like using the bootable USB-stick.

Comment: no, booting happens before you ever reach the OS and is BIOS-specific.

Comment: Normally on the SGO2 it should be done using "power on+volume down". I have tested several distros and never had any issues until after I installed Ubuntu. I can see the USB-stick flashing, indicating that the SGO2 recognize it. Holding down SHIFT makes me boot into the GRUB Menu, but it doesnt show up until after I am logged into Ubuntu.

Comment: This is strange because getting to the temporary menu should be independent of the operating system. Can you use "power on+volume down" to boot a USB drive with some other Linux system? Can you use "power on+volume down" to get into the UEFI menus and modify the boot order?

Comment: Yes, I agree, very strange! Unfortunately, I only have one USB-stick which has USB-C. The SGO2 only has one USB-C out port. "power on+volume up" boots me directly into UEFI and USB boot is set to top priority, secure boot is disabled etc. I can't remember from the top of my head, but I believe balena-etcher doesnt format the USB-stick to FAT32, which I suspect might be causing problems (although strange that I have had no other problems with Arch for instance, flashing using balena) I am going to try to find a way to format the USB-C stick to FAT32

Comment: UEFI Settings:

Security

UEFI PW= Clean

Secure boot= Disabled

TPM= Not Installed

TPM= Disabled

SMT= Enabled

Devices

Everything enabled

Boot configuration

USB Storage

Windows Boot Manager

Network boot-IPV4

Network boot-IPV6

Internal Storage

- Advanced options:

Enable alternate boot sequence= Enabled

Enable IPV6 for PXE Netwoork boot=Enabled

Enable Boot from USB Devices= Enabled

Enable Boot Configuration Lock= Disabled